# Ansible: "msg": "basic: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 503"

Tags: linux, ansible

I have ansible version 2.4.2. Trying to integrate Ansible control machine (RHEL) with Windows.
When I run the ping command :

```
ansible wmdev (hostname) -i hosts -m win_ping
```

Getting below error while connecting to windows machine:

```
wmdev | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "basic: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 503",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I am not sure what his error code means. I tried using Kerberos, Basic, ntlm. But no success. Please help.

Comment: _"I am not sure what his error code means"_  > it would help if the playbook did return the actual error message! Because a plain Google search for `HTTP 503` suggests that the web service simply refuses to answer because it is overloaded, or you have reached your quota (max # of queries per hour, max # of open sessions, etc)

Comment: Authentication error would result in 401, authorization error in 403.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error.
The problem turned out to be proxy.
just run `export http_proxy=""`.

Answer (score 2):

This can also occur if you have http_poxy or HTTP_PROXY set as an environment variable in your linux session.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug this issue using following methods.

--> manually ping the destination server ip address. if you are not able to reach then it should be network issue.

--> Verify you host file. It should have following vars to connect to windows machine:

```
ansible_user=<user>
ansible_password=<password>
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_ssh_port=5985
```

--> winrm should be enabled on your windows machine.

--> target windows machine execution policy should not be unrestricted.

--> verify net firewall rule "Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)", if not available set it.